# SQL to select specific rows from a Teradata table

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, recursive-query

[image: Table rows]

I have a Teradata table with information about job runs. The attached image shows information stored in table.
There are multiple entries for each job in a day. I am in the process of automating job status based on the start and end time. I want to pick start_time of job V1S0 and end_time of job V5S0 highlighted in red from this table(the job highlighted in yellow run in a single batch). Can someone share SQL to do this.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: How to identify the batch?

Comment: there is a column for batch name as well. All these jobs belong to the same batch name

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*, to get  V1S0 start and V5SO end.

```
select batch,
       min(case when job_name = 'V1S0' then start_time end),
       max(case when job_name = 'V5S0' then end_time end)
from tablename
where batch = <some batch identifier>
group by batch
```

Comment: the sql you have provided picks the end_time of the last run of that job V5S0 which is highlighted in green in attached image. 
I need the end_time of job V5S0 highlighted in red.
The issue is i am looking the start and end time of batch where the start time of batch is on one date and the end time is next day/date. e.g in above scenario the batch starts with job V1S0 on 29/01/2020 20:39:04 and batch completes when job V5S0 completed next day 30/01/2020 02:27:08. Both these are highlighted in red and i need to pick these timestamps only.

Comment: Doesn't "_the job highlighted in yellow run in a single batch_" mean you know when a batcha starts and ends? Use the WHERE clause to include only "the yellow part".

Comment: All these jobs run under the same batch name. There are multiple runs in one day. I just need to get the run hightlighted in yellow with start_time and end_time higlighted in red.